# Spring-boot: Beans are null during unit/integration test

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I am new to sprint-boot. I have a spring-boot application which is working fine in it's regular path. Now as I am trying to write unit/integration tests, I find that my beans are null.

**I appreciate any help on understanding why are they null and how to fix it. It seems that it is not able to pick up properties from the yml at all.Please let me know if any more clarification is required.**

## To clarify the structure:

**The main class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationConfiguration.class)
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

**The properties file (src/main/java/resources/application.yml)**

```
http:
  url:
    protocol: http
    baseUrl: ${CONNECTOR_BASE_URL}
    connectorListUrl : connectors
```

**The configuration class that is using the above properties (ApplicationConfiguration.java) is :**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "http.url")
@Validated
@Data
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

  private String protocol;
  private String baseUrl;
  private String connectorListUrl;
}
```

**Now, the simplified version of the class(ContinuousMonitorServiceTask.java that I am trying to write my test on, looks like :**

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ContinuousMonitorServiceTask extends TimerTask {

  @Autowired MonitorHttpClient httpClient;

  @Autowired ApplicationConfiguration config;

 

  @PostConstruct
  public void setUp() {
    connectorListUrl =
        config.getProtocol() + "://" + config.getBaseUrl() + "/" + config.getConnectorListUrl();

    connectorListHeaderParams.clear();
    connectorListHeaderParams.put("Accept", "application/json");
    connectorListHeaderParams.put("Content-Type", "application/json");

    connectorListGetRequest = new HttpGet(connectorListUrl);
    httpClient.setHeader(connectorListGetRequest, connectorListHeaderParams);
  }

  public void fetchList() {

    try {

      response = httpClient.callApi("Get Connector List", connectorListGetRequest);
      log.info(response.toString());

      connectorListResponseHandler(response);

    } catch (Exception e) {

      log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

The above code is working fine when I am executing.

Now **when I am writing test**, I **need to mock api calls** and hence, I have used **MOCK-SERVER** and my **testSimple1** test has passed which is a simple test to see if the mock server can start and return expected response. However, while debugging **simpleTest2**, I am seeing

- **monitorTask** is null
- **appConfig** is null
- **monitorTask** is null

Although, I have **src/test/resources/application.yml** as:

```
http:
    url:
        protocol: http
        baseUrl: 127.0.0.1:8080
        connectorListUrl : connectors
```

My guess is that appConfig is not able to pick up the properties from application.yml during test and hence everything is null.However, I am not 100% sure about what is happening in real time.

Here is how my test class looks like (Kind of dirty code, but I am putting it in it's current state to show what I have tried so far):

```
//@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
//@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.yml")
//@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
//@SpringApplicationConfiguration(ApplicationConfiguration.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationConfiguration.class)
//@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationConfiguration.class)
public class ContinousMonitorTest {

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Mock private MonitorHttpClient httpClient;

  @Mock private ApplicationConfiguration appConfig;

  @InjectMocks
  //@MockBean
  //@Autowired
  private ContinuousMonitorServiceTask monitorTask;

  TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

  private static ClientAndServer mockServer;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void startServer() {
    mockServer = startClientAndServer(8080);
  }

  @AfterClass
  public static void stopServer() {
    mockServer.stop();
  }

  private void createExpectationForInvalidAuth() {
    new MockServerClient("127.0.0.1", 8080)
            .when(
                    request()
                            .withMethod("GET")
                            .withPath("/validate")
                            .withHeader("\"Content-type\", \"application/json\""),
                            //.withBody(exact("{username: 'foo', password: 'bar'}")),
                    exactly(1))
            .respond(
                    response()
                            .withStatusCode(401)
                            .withHeaders(
                                    new Header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"),
                                    new Header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=86400"))
                            .withBody("{ message: 'incorrect username and password combination' }")
                            .withDelay(TimeUnit.SECONDS,1)
            );
  }


  private GenericResponse hitTheServerWithGETRequest() {
    String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/validate";
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet post = new HttpGet(url);
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    GenericResponse response=null;

    try {
      StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity("{username: 'foo', password: 'bar'}");
      post.getRequestLine();
     // post.setEntity(stringEntity);
      response=client.execute(post, new GenericResponseHandler());

    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return response;
  }

  @Test
  public void testSimple1() throws Exception{

    createExpectationForInvalidAuth();

    GenericResponse response = hitTheServerWithGETRequest();
    System.out.println("response customed : " + response.getResponse());
    assertEquals(401, response.getStatusCd());


    monitorTask.fetchConnectorList();
  }

  @Test
  public void testSimple2() throws Exception{

    monitorTask.fetchConnectorList();
  }
```

Comment: Looks like you did not initialize `Mockito`. Add `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` to a method annotated with `@Before`. Using the `MockitoJUnitRunner`does that automatically, however if you do not use it, you need to do it manually.

Comment: Also it does not look like you defined any behaviour for the `Mocks` you are injecting into `ContinuousMonitorServiceTask`. Might be that you use the wrong annotations for what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @second  suggested above, I made a change in the **testSimple2** test to look like and that resolved the above mentioned problem.

```
@Test
public void testSimple2() throws Exception{

  mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(monitorTask).build();
  Mockito.when(appConfig.getProtocol()).thenReturn("http");
  Mockito.when(appConfig.getBaseUrl()).thenReturn("127.0.0.1:8080");
  Mockito.when(appConfig.getConnectorListUrl()).thenReturn("validate");
  Mockito.when(httpClient.callApi(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenCallRealMethod();

  monitorTask.setUp();
  monitorTask.fetchConnectorList();
}
```

**Alternatively, could have done:**

```
@Before
public void init()
{
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify whether you changed the `annotations` for the fields or if `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup` has some kind of effect on them?

Comment: I did not make any change in any annotation that is described in the question. Thanks for your answer and reminder on this.

Comment: I just wondered why the `Mocks` are working now. According to your answer you did not add `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`, so afaik they should still be `null`? But according to your answer that is not the case anymore.

Comment: I guess they both serve the same purpose( Please correct me if I am wrong). I tried both with same annotations and they both worked and fails if none of them exist

Comment: I didn't find  any evidence in the docu of `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup` that this is supposed to have an effect on mockito, but mabye I missed that part. You are still using the `SpringRunner` ?

Comment: Yes only annotation that is working with this structure is @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)